# Where can I find info to write Sharepoint Specifications for my Sharepoint team?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, documentation

Where can I find the information on how to write specifications for my Sharepoint team? And lets assume I've never written any sort of project document and don't know for sure officially the right ways to do things in Sharepoint and that all I know comes from poking around.

Where can I find that info?

Comment: Could you please review? I think "where can I find the info" is less opinion based.

Comment: Functional or technical specifications? Anyway: either case, the only good way is to know/have experience on the subject... That's true for any technical area, but it's particularly important for SharePoint, as there's so many approaches/concurrent concepts/traps/dead-ends/. So maybe you'd need to hire someone who knows a bit SharePoint, or considering a good and intensive training. Would you ask where you can find information on how to do surgery (because you can't afford to hire a surgeon/go to a medical school for 10 years)?

Comment: Believe me I know. We can't afford Sharepoint Devs and myself and my boss are too far removed from anybody who can do anything about it. Good for me I guess because I wouldn't have gotten this job otherwise. Bad for me because I hate this and I don't want to do it and I'm also not any good at it. I want to write something that passes for acceptable and get back to dev work.

So what you're telling me is to just give up and don't do it? Because I don't have years to gain the experience I'm missing and there's no other option.

Comment: Also, I don't know the difference between functional and technical specifications. I assume functional? Its supposed to tell our own team and other Sharepoint using units how we would prefer that they use Sharepoint.

Comment: So you want to coach the German (they always win) Soccer team but don't have a clue what a soccer ball looks like? SharePoint is a beast, a good SP team has about as many members as a soccer team. To coach them you need to understand all positions, roles and plays. You don't have to master them yourself... but if you don't know the distinction between Functional and Technical... I fear you don't even know what  ball is. (sorry to be harsh.. better break your dreams now than later)

Comment: I GET IT! OK I GET IT!

Now lets pretend there's literally nothing I can do about it (because there isn't) and I have to do the assignment anyway. Surely there's something that somebody somewhere wrote that might be of use. Could we maybe skip the part about why this is a terrible idea (believe me I know this is a terrible idea) and actually try being helpful rather than just telling me why I suck?

EDIT: Also, I know the difference between the words "functional" and "technical" and I can make an educated guess how that differentiates specifications but I don't want to assume.

Comment: Ok. To add something that might be helpful. I don't have to write a world class enterprise specifications document. I just have to write a document that tells new team members and other Sharepoint users how we do things and how we'd like them to do things. In the process, I'd like to make some improvements to our process by learning some sharepoint best practices but strictly speaking the document only has to contain our stunted inadequate knowledge. Sorry but this is something I realized after posting. Do you know anything to help with that?

Comment: I've touched most of the Sharepoint components at some point. I just need help organizing. My brain just isn't built to come up with organization systems but I can use other people's stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thinking about this in a different way:

Who is going to be reading this document? What do they expect to see in it? Ask them. And then ask for feedback when your first draft is completed.

Tech design documents vary widely in structure and form, between organizations and even within them.  Take your best guess, spend a couple hours writing up a very rough draft, then ask your colleagues to tell you what's missing or what's redundant, or what needs more or less detail. Then iterate and make it better.

It sounds like your organization doesn't have a lot of experience with formalized procedures for software design. You have a golden opportunity here to establish yourself as the expert.

Comment: It would be a golden opportunity for someone who wants to be that expert (I didn't want this assignment and don't want others like it and thats hurting me as much as my inexperience with this type of task, I want to code one of these days). But thank you, this was very helpful and constructive. Having principles and method like this is probably better for me than pointing me to a 1500 page book I'm not likely to retain. I do better figuring things out. And you just linked this project to my coding experience.

Comment: Who is going to be reading this? New people on my team and Sharepoint power users in other groups who want to create and manage their own sites (my team is the core Sharepoint support team, we used to be able to afford actual experts). What do they expect to see? You're right I should ask. I expect they would want a complete tutorial but we can point them to that. What I'm supposed to provide is how WE want them to approach things.